# Apply scrollIntoView function in to JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using JQuery show and hide function, it works like when you click on image it opens a information log. The information log opens at the top of the page, so I need to make that when you click on the image on bottom on the page it scroll you up to the content.

JQuery what I am using for my hide and show content:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.showSingle').click(function() {
    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
    jQuery('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
  });
});
```

Scrolintoview function that I tried to use:

```
function myFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("targetDiv");
  elmnt.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Content from witch I am calling both functions:

```
<a  onclick="myFunction()" class="showSingle" target="{$ID}">
    //HTML content here
</a>
```

Content what I am calling to shop up at the top of the page:

```
<div id="div{$ID}" class="targetDiv SlideDiv">
    //HTML content here 
</div>
```

I tried to combine this two JS function but only `jQuery('.targetDiv').hide()` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your target div

```
<div id="div{$ID}" class="targetDiv SlideDiv">
//HTML content here 
</div>
```

has some id and the classes `targetDiv` and `SlideDiv`.

`document.getElementById("targetDiv")` tries to find an element with the id `targetDiv` but your element does not have this id, but is has a class with the same name.

You need to find the element by its class which can be done in a few ways:

**1**

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("targetDiv")[0];
```

**2**

```
var elem = document.querySelector(".targetDiv");
```

**3**

```
var elem = $(".targetDiv")[0];
```

Comment: The please post your full js and html code. There could be other factors that I am unaware of.

Comment: It is wierd. It works sometimes but maybe 1 out of 10 and not on all images.

Comment: I can only help you more if you post your full code

Comment: Full code is just too big with all smartys etc. I found out where can be an error. targetDiv is used by 20 other elements. They have theire own unique Id's but they are generated with foreach so i cant put it in JS

Comment: Then you need to find a way to identify the div that you want to scroll to. I cannot help you with that, sorry